# Meitrack device what to return to confirm server recived data

Tags: vb.net, tcp, gprs

I am communicating with a meitrack odb device, i can receive data but when i set the protocol to"Event report needs servers confiramtion " i get and extra field (i resume this is the cache count". In the documentation i can only find "AFF" to return to the device, this doesnt seem to clear the cache though.

***Deleting a GPRS Event In the Cache Zone – AFF
GPRS Setting    AFF, Number of deleted GPRS events
GPRS Responding AFF, Number of remaining caches,Command type, (-) Latitude,(-) Longitude,Data and

```
time,Status,Number of satellites,GSM signal status,Speed,Direction,Horizontal positioning accuracy,Altitude,Mileage,Run time,Base station information,I/O port
```

status,Analog input value
Description Number of deleted GPRS events: hexadecimal string. The default value is 1.
Number  of  remaining  caches:  total  number  of  events  in  internal  flash  memory. Hexadecimal string.
Applicable Model    All
Example
GPRS Sending    @@h27,353358017784062,AFF,1*0B\r\n
GPRS Receiving  $$h28,353358017784062,AFF,OK*3D\r\n

Answer (score 1):

you can not communicate with device over TCP/UDP . device ip and port are not static or stable . its changing i mean dynamic . if you want to send any command to device you have to send sms . this is so far i figure out.

Comment: I don't thinks so. IP's are changed after 45 minutes, almost in every network provider. So we can keep the ip from units latest reporting messages and sent the commands to unit.

Answer (score 1):

When using "Event report needs servers confirmation" the server has to respond to the incoming messages, something like "OK, I've received that, you can drop that report".

The tracker opens a socket to the server on a given port, and keeps that alive to read incoming (device to server) and to write outgoing (server to device) messages. The device tries to re-send the message if there was no confirmation - and tells the size of it's cache, to check if there are remaining messages still.

It is not straightforward how to confirm, but the protocol docs describe the process in detail. Eg. for "Trackids" devices (I've tried these): http://www.meitrack.com/cd-download/Protocols/MEITRACK_Trackids_GPRS_Protocol.pdf

The messages from the device have a message identifier, an IMEI, a message type and multiple data packets. The server has to respond with the same identifier and message type, tell how many data packets can be deleted, and also add a checksum. If these are consistent with the original message, then the device drops the data packets from the cache, and sends the subsequent messages (data packets).